# How do you call "Document Format" programmatically from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I'm writing a simple VS add-in and would like to programmatically invoke the "Document Format" option (under Edit) within code. Google isn't being very friendly to me today....

Comment: Have you tried Resharper? It can reformat the whole solution for you in one go. (I assume this does not help but I must have tried... ;-) )

Comment: Nah, just trying to roll my own little tool to automatically close braces (yes, I know Resharper does that too, but where's the fun in that??)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Command cmd = _applicationObject.Commands.Item("Edit.FormatDocument", -1);
object dummy = null;
_applicationObject.Commands.Raise(cmd.Guid, cmd.ID, ref dummy, ref dummy);
```

Comment: As it is a first time to check it, i couldnt understand. Can u please specify type of the '_applicationObject' and its namespace.I browsed a little bit that i should use EnvDTE80 namespace but i couldnt proceed. Any codesnippet will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a reference to your document (of type Window), and you have a reference to the _DTE object, you can call it like this:

```
myDocument.Activate();
myDTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument", string.Empty);
```

Most of the time, you can get a reference to the _DTE object from the parameters passed into your add-in.

Comment: Is there any way to format document without opening it? I want to format all documents in project with one click.

Comment: I don't believe so. You could open, format, and then close the document.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the standard command editors, called with the [VSStd2KCmdId.FORMATDOCUMENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd2kcmdid(VS.80).aspx) command enumeration.