# API for indentation of generated C#

Tags: c#, indentation, generated-code

In my current project, we have a couple of code generator routines to help us through some mindless tasks. Everything works fine from the technical point of view, so that might be more a curiosity than a real issue: when I open a newly generated piece of code, it is (of course) not properly indented (although syntactically correct).

Now, the question: is there an API somewhere that can be used to indent a piece of C# code? Much like what happens when I use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> in VS2010.

Just to clarify, I am looking for a function like that:

```
string GetProperlyFormattedCode(string notFormattedCode);
```

where `notFormattedCode` is a piece of valid c# source code, and the output of the function is the same code after application of formatting rules. In other words, I am looking for the function that lies behind the "Edit -> Advanced -> Format selection" command of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you want indenting when you generate the code? Would the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter.aspx help?

Comment: Hi, I think it is not what I am looking for - I'm editing the question with an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call "Document Format" programmatically from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813119/how-do-you-call-document-format-programmatically-from-c)

Comment: The question you referenced is regarding formatting from the "add-in context". That would require you to make an add-in. This question does not involve addins.

Answer (score 7):

To indent code just use Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp nuget package and .NET framework 4.6+. Sample code:

```
public string ArrangeUsingRoslyn(string csCode) {
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode);
    var root = tree.GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace();
    var ret = root.ToFullString();
    return ret;
}
```

One-liner:

```
csCode = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode).GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
```

You may also use [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/) to sort methods in your cs file, organize usings, create regions, etc. Note that NArrange does not indent anything.

Comment: It's the best solution, save my time. Don't know why still not a accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to answer:

[How do you call "Document Format" programmatically from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813119/how-do-you-call-document-format-programmatically-from-c)

The short is use Visual Studio's object model to call the format command.

Comment: That doesn't answer this question.  The question you referenced is regarding formatting from the "add-in context".  That would require you to make an add-in.  This question does not involve addins.

Comment: I was suggesting that he can programatically leverage the code formatting built into VS, which by chance happens to be what the OP used as an example (<kbd>CTRL+E, D</kbd>). Why invent something when you can try to leverage the formatter you already like?